# Contacting loki from fluentbit output plugin

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit, grafana-loki

I am collecting logs from a kubernetes cluster using fluentbit, having an output that connect to loki to send them there.

This is my loki configuration at fluentbit configmap file

Since loki is deployed at `loki` namespace, and fluentbit at `fluentbit` namespace I am using to contact loki: `host loki.loki.svc.cluster.local`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name docker
        Format json
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level info
        Parsers_File parsers.conf
        Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On
    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 100MB
        Skip_Long_Lines On
    [INPUT]
        Name systemd
        Tag host.*
        Systemd_Filter _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service
        Read_From_Tail On
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
    [OUTPUT]
        Name stdout
        Match kube.*
        Format json
        Json_date_key timestamp
        Json_date_format iso8601
    [OUTPUT]
        Name loki
        Match kube.*
        host loki.loki.svc.cluster.local 
        port 3100
        tenant_id ""
        Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
        auto_kubernetes_labels false
        line_format json
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: fluent-bit
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: fluent-bit
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-21T13:53:14Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: fluent-bit
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluent-bit
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.8
    helm.sh/chart: fluent-bit-0.19.1
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: fluent-bit
```

But I got this error in my fluentbit logs.

```
[2021/10/21 14:59:59] [error] [output:loki:loki.1] loki.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100, HTTP status=400 Not retrying.
1:2: parse error: unexpected left brace '{'
```

Looks like that is not the correct format, and sometimes I got this another message with the same configuration (weird):

```
[2021/10/21 14:59:59] [error] [output:loki:loki.1] loki.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100, HTTP status=400 Not retrying.
1:2: parse error: unexpected left brace '{'
```

Like I would have to explicitly specify the POST endpoint on loki to push logs there, [this one](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#post-apiprompush) `/loki/api/v1/push`

But in general terms, I am getting the most the `400` bad syntax error.
How can I contact loki from fluentbit configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use curly braces for the labeling, this would do:

```
[OUTPUT]
    ...
    Labels job="fluent-bit"
    ...
```

See the example here: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/loki

Comment: I remove them, but i got the same result.